# Call chrome extension API from GWT

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I need to send message from GWT frontend to chrome extension. For this purpose I use JSNI in GWT and call the following method:

```
static native void sendMessageToChromeExtension() /*-{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...);
}-*/;
```

However, this does not work and I'm getting:

```
Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Webpages cannot *normally* call chrome APIs (with the exception of [inline install](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)).

To achieve what you wish to do, you need to follow the procedure outlined [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).
Suppose your frontend lives at http://example.com/, then you need to declare in the extension's manifest that you expect messages from this domain:

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

Only then will `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` be exposed to the webpage. Note that you'll also need to provide the extension's id.

Comment: I already added web page to externally_connectable, and it works when I call it directly in dev console

Comment: To clarify, where are you getting this message then?

Comment: In dev console but if I trigger it over GWT.

Comment: @Le_Coeur Can you call if from the webpage's console itself? If not, something's wrong in the setup, if yes, something's wrong on the JSNI side.

Comment: @Le_Coeur Glad it worked; I'm going to keep my answer as it's relevant, but yours clearly needs to be marked as such when you're able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem I need to call *chrome* from *$wnd* (window) object. The following works:

```
static native void sendMessageToChromeExtension() /*-{
    $wnd.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...);
}-*/;
```